# Create bean configured in external jar spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I created a jar which has the configuration for RestTemplate. For example,

java-client jar:

com.java.rest.client

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateClient {

public RestTemplateClient() {
}

@Bean(
    name = {"restClient"}
)
RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
    //HTTP configurations
}
}
```

I am using this jar in another spring boot application. I want to use the same restTemplate configuration available in the jar. But on Autowiring the restTemplate, it throws Null Pointer Exception.

In the Sprint boot project..
com.example.auth

```
@Service
public class Auth {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("restClient")
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public void sampleMethod()
        throws ResourceAccessException, Exception {
    
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler); //throws NullPointerException
    HttpHeaders headers = createHttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<T> entity = new HttpEntity<T>(data, headers);

    restTemplate.exchange("url",
            GET,
            entity,
            class);
  }
}
```

I am new to Spring boot, can someone please guide?

Comment: Where do you use the Auth class? Can you show an example? Because if you would have configured everything correctly, Spring would throw a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, if it cannot find a bean implementation for an autowired field. Do you create an instance of the Auth class yourself instead of having it injected by Spring?

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null`, it will blow up at startup with an `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. If that isn't the case you are creating an instance of `Auth` yourself (or at least outside the scope of Spring). If that isn't the case you aren't showing the actual code that is being used. See also https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/

Comment: @dunni You are correct.. I was creating the class using the new keyword. I used Autowired and everything is working fine.. Thanks for the help !!

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the help !! I used Autowired and everything is working

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way to do that is using `spring.factories` mechanism.

Read more information about it in [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

If you have a configuration that should be loaded automatically by spring boot projects, you can create a file: `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` in the `java-client` module.

During the startup of spring boot application, spring boot looks for the `spring.factories` files and loads the configuration specified there.

The file is a properties file where you can specify different things, in this case you should place something like that:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.yourorg.yourproject.RestTemplateClient
```

You should treat the rest-client module as any other dependency, define it in maven/gradle and so forth.